# how can I clear text from a Text widget on Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I made a statusbar on Tkinter and I want there to show up some values. Sometimes that value changes, so I need the statusbar to change to. When I run my program the value shows just fine, but when I change the value and I insert it, the old value stays and the new one is printed next to the old one.

My question is how can I first delete the first one and then add the other one?

```
from tkinter import *
class lol:

   def __init__(self, window):
       frame = Frame(window)
       frame.grid()

       self.statusbarTotal = Text(window, width= 8, height= 1, bd=1, relief= SUNKEN)
       self.statusbarTotal.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=W)

       self.presetButton1 = Button(window, text=" 10 ", command=self.preset10)
       self.presetButton1.grid(row=2, column=0)

       self.presetButton2 = Button(window, text=" 30 ", command=self.preset30)
       self.presetButton2.grid(row=2, column=1)


   def preset10(self):
          global waitingTime
          waitingTime = 600
          self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(waitingTime/60))
          print(waitingTime)

   def preset30(self):
          global waitingTime
          waitingTime = 1800
          self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(waitingTime/60))
          print(waitingTime)

tk = Tk()
b = lol(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using the documented `delete` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your indention issues.
You need to change:

```
def preset10(self):
    global waitingTime
    waitingTime = 600
    self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(waitingTime/60))
    print(waitingTime)

def preset30(self):
    global waitingTime
    waitingTime = 1800
    self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(waitingTime/60))
    print(waitingTime)
```

To:

```
def preset10(self):
    global waitingTime
    waitingTime = 600
    self.statusbarTotal.delete(1.0, END)
    self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(waitingTime/60))
    print(waitingTime)

def preset30(self):
    global waitingTime
    waitingTime = 1800
    self.statusbarTotal.delete(1.0, END)
    self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(waitingTime/60))
    print(waitingTime)
```

However your program shows all the data on one line so I am not sure why you are trying to insert values on the 13th line of the text box. If you can provide context or a better example I can provide a better answer.

However you should really get rid of your `global` variables all together as this is considered bad programing to use.

Instead your code should use class attributes. Something like this:

```
from tkinter import *


class lol:

    def __init__(self, window):
        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.grid()
        # uss self. to make a variable name a class attribute
        self.waitingTime = 0

        self.statusbarTotal = Text(window, width= 8, height= 1, bd=1, relief= SUNKEN)
        self.statusbarTotal.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.presetButton1 = Button(window, text=" 10 ", command=self.preset10)
        self.presetButton1.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.presetButton2 = Button(window, text=" 30 ", command=self.preset30)
        self.presetButton2.grid(row=2, column=1)


    def preset10(self):
        self.waitingTime = 600
        self.statusbarTotal.delete(1.0, END)
        self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(self.waitingTime/60))
        print(self.waitingTime)

    def preset30(self):
        self.waitingTime = 1800
        self.statusbarTotal.delete(1.0, END)
        self.statusbarTotal.insert(13.0, int(self.waitingTime/60))
        print(self.waitingTime)

tk = Tk()
b = lol(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is just a piece of the software that i made that' s why I inserted the values on the 13th line. But thanks a lot, you really helped me out!

Comment: @AntonLambrecht If my answer has worked for you please select the check box next to my answer to indicate you have got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities.

The first is that `insert` will, well, *insert* the new text into the existing text. So you have to use `delete` to remove the part that you don't want anymore.

Another solution, which is simpler I think, is don't use a `Text` widget but instead use `Label`, which allows you to set and replace the `text` it displays all at once.  You can't manually edit the text in a Label widget but I suppose for a status bar that is not what you want anyway.